# C/C++ Printing bytes in hex, getting weird hex values

Tags: c++, c

I am using the following to print out numbers from an array in hex:

```
char buff[1000];

// Populate array....

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    printf("[%d] %02x\n", i,buff[i]);
}
```

but I sometimes print weird values:

```
byte[280] 00     
byte[281] 00     
byte[282] 0a     
byte[283] fffffff4         // Why is this a different length?
byte[284] 4e      
byte[285] 66      
byte[286] 0a
```

Why does this print 'fffffff4'?

Comment: please show `// Populate array....`

Comment: One safe play, use `char buff[1000] = {0};` to avoid using any un-init-ed value.

Comment: yes, you need to show the code where the bug is.

Comment: You appear to be targeting a system where plain `char` is a signed type (and `int` is 32 bits).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `%02hhx` as the format string.

From [CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), `%02x` accepts `unsigned int`. When you pass the arguments to `printf()`, which is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), `buff[i]` is automatically converted to `int`. Then the format specifier `%02x` makes `printf()` interprets the value as `int`, so potential negative values like `(char)-1` get interpreted and printed as `(int)-1`, which is the cause of what you observed.

It can also be inferred that your platform has signed `char` type, and a 32-bit `int` type.

The length modifier `hh` will tell `printf()` to interpret whatever supplied as `char` type, so `%hhx` is the correct format specifier for `unsigned char`.

Alternatively, you can cast the data to `unsigned char` before printing. Like

```
printf("[%d] %02x\n", i, (unsigned char)buff[i]);
```

This can also prevent negative values from showing up as too long, as `int` can (almost) always contain `unsigned char` value.

---

See the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    signed char a = +1, b = -1;
    printf("%02x %02x %02hhx %02hhx\n", a, b, a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
01 ffffffff 01 ff
```

Comment: *"`%02x` accepts `unsigned int`, which causes your `buff[i]` to be promoted to `int`"* This is somewhat misleading. Promotion happens because of *default argument promotions* on variable argument functions. Format string conversion specifiers have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @user694733 How can that sentence be improved, in your opinion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd like to see distinction between promotion and interpretation. Promotion happens automatically to `int` before `printf` is entered, and interpretation to `unsigned int` of happens inside `printf` because of `%x`.

Answer (score 5):

Your platform apparantly has signed `char`. On platforms where `char` is unsigned the output would be `f4`.

When calling a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) any integer argument smaller than `int` gets promoted to `int`.

A `char` value of `f4` (`-12` as a `signed char`) has the sign bit set, so when converted to `int` becomes `fffffff4` (still `-12` but now as a `signed int`) in your case.

`%x02` causes `printf` to treat the argument as an `unsigned int` and will print it using *at least* 2 hexadecimal digits.
The output doesn't fit in 2 digits, so as many as are required are used.

Hence the output `fffffff4`.

To fix it, either declare your array `unsigned char buff[1000];` or cast the argument:

```
    printf("[%d] %02x\n", i, (unsigned char)buff[i]);
```